# symfony2 + assetic : how to restrict a css to a print when using {% javascripts %}

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, twig, media-queries

In my symfony 2 application, I have :

```
<link href="{{ asset('stylesheets/backend/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' media='print'>
```

I also have a vendor css file which modifies it and needs to be placed after. This one is included in my {% stylesheets %} block :

```
{% stylesheets
    'stylesheets/backend/style.css'

    filter='?yui_css, cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Now the thing is if I put the css for print in the stylesheets block, I lose the media=print argument and things get messed.

How can I include a css into a stylesheets block and restric its usage to a print media query ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to approach this:

1) You could separate your print-specific stylesheet into a new `stylesheets` block (you can have as many of these as you need), and simply add the `media='print'` attribute to the `<link>` element.

It would look something like this:

```
{% stylesheets
    'foo.css'
    'bar.css'

    filter='?yui_css, cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% stylesheets
    'vendor_stylesheet_with_print_styles.css'

    filter='?yui_css, cssrewrite'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" media="print" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

2) If you don't need to [support IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), you can use a media query inside the CSS file that needs to modify it:

```
@media print {
    ... styles go here ...
}
```

Comment: hmm, it's a vendor css so I coant' put it inside a media query. are you saying we can add a media print attribute to a specific file listed within a stylesheets twig block ?

Comment: You can add 'media="print"' to the <link> element for a stylesheet block, and you can have multiple stylesheet blocks (to separate stylesheets meant for print and those meant for desktop). I've edited my answer to hopefully clarify.